# How to change getByte to writeString in java

Tags: java, string, methods, thermal-printer, escpos

So We Have A Problem with getBytes syntax when we want to change from this format

```
int hours = duration / 3600;
        int mins = (duration - (hours * 3600))/60;
        printer.write(new byte[] {ESC, '@', ESC, 0x61, 0x01});
        printer.write(String.format("%s\n", locationexample).getBytes());
        printer.write(new byte[] {0x1b, 0x61, 0x00});
        printer.write(String.format("%s / %s\n", lic, VEHICLE_TYPE.values()[type]).getBytes());
        printer.write(String.format("%s\n", cashier).getBytes());
        printer.write(String.format("In     : %s-%s\n", df.format(in), gateIn).getBytes());
        printer.write(String.format("Out    : %s-%s\n\n", df.format(out), gate).getBytes());
        printer.write(String.format("Period : %d Jam %d Menit\n\n", hours, mins).getBytes());
        printer.write(String.format("Cost Parking    Rp %,11d\n\n", fee).replaceAll(",", "\\.").getBytes());
        printer.write(new byte[] {0x1b, 0x61, 0x01});
        printer.write("Greetinga\n".getBytes());      
        printer.write("Greetingb\n".getBytes());                 
        printer.write(new byte[] {0x1b, 0x64, 0x05});
        printer.write(new byte[] {0x1d, 0x56, 0x42, 0x00});        
        printer.close();
        {
```

To this format

```
serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, '@', 0x1b, 0x61, 0x01}));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, '!', 0x08}));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, 'E', 0x1b}));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {GS, '!', 0x10, 0x01}));
        serialPort.writeString(String.format("%s\n", "TOP"));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, 'J', 0x4A}));
        serialPort.writeString(new String(new byte[] {ESC, 'J', 0x4A}));
```

Can someone help this out??

Thanks all..

Comment: So, _what_ is the problem?

Comment: You could start by trying with using [the other constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) for `String`; the one that takes a charset as a parameter. If you don't provide a charset, the byte array will be interpreted with the platform's default charset encoding.

Comment: The real problem is we already change it to the upper format.

Comment: The real problem we can't the result to the printer even after we already change it to the upper format.

Base on the situation is im missing something?
Because we don't get any error massage..

Thanks

Comment: `String.format("%s\n", "TOP")` *Huh?* Why not just write `"TOP\n"`?

Comment: Thanks Andreas,, will change it,,
But can you help why i can't print ?
because it's the real problem, after we change to format below